# What is the Eraser Trick in StarCraft?

Tags: terminology, starcraft

What is the eraser trick mentioned in this StarCraft video?

Comment: [Link to the Meta discussion opened on this subject](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/845/how-to-emphasize-that-starcraft-is-not-starcraft-2 "How to differentiate old games (Starcraft vs Starcraft II)?")

Comment: Could add "Brood War" in the title. Even though you might not be playing the expansion (which you really should), it'll help differentiate. It's how TeamLiquid does it.

Comment: Hopefully people realize as they're answering the question that the Eraser Trick doesn't exist in SC2

Comment: @Atav32 That wouldn't work as Brood War is an expansion, and not everyone plays Brood War when they play the original StarCraft.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a summary of what it does:

"Doing the Eraser trick is very easy, you only need two or more Science Vessels with Irradiate researched. To do the trick, simply have your two Science Vessels irradiate each other, and fly them over or near the units you wish to kill. Since Science Vessels are not biological units, Irradiate has no effect on them; however, Irradiate's splash damage hurts surrounding biological units."

taken from http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Science_Vessel_Eraser

Comment: It's worth noting that Science Vessels have a fairly wide radius (which affects the area of damage) as well as decent speed, so they are perhaps the ideal air unit to irradiate.

Comment: @JoeyAdams I think it's more about convenience in the SK Terran build order. If you're massing science vessles, it's hard to have the gas and Starport time to build other air units.

Comment: @JoeyAdams "Irradiate is an offensive spell cast by the Terran Science Vessel and surrounds the targeted unit with an aura of radioactive energy. It can be cast on any unit (unless in Stasis) and deals an equal amount of damage (250) over a period of 37 in-game seconds to all biological units within a 2 hex radius of the affected unit. " (from Liquipedia). SV's sight radius doesn't impact the damage dealt by an Irradiate spell cast on it.